# Omens font was not aligned correctly in mobile versions

Tags: html, css, typography

Please find the screenshot
[click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vqqY.jpg)

HTML and Css Code

```css
#tataCapital #employee-verify .employment-verification-form .employee-form .form-group.s {
    width: 95%;
}
#tataCapital #employee-verify .employment-verification-form .employee-form .form-group input {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 5px;
    border-radius: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding-left: 21px;
    color: #211e1e;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group s">
  <label class="control-label">Date of joining</label>
  <input name="joiningDate" class="form-control date-picker hasDatepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
</div>
```

Comment: show me the css & html code

Comment: show your code here

Answer (score 0):

i think you have set fixed height to the `input` tag, then you arrange the value by padding, thats why your value not showing fully. remove your input height see the code below

```css
input {
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" value="name" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did your remove your browser catch ? , which browser you have this problem ?

Comment: Please change 

font-weight: normal;

I hope it will be helpfully

Comment: We had removed the cache, problem is in chrome browser and made font-weight normal, but no use